# What is an "unchecked conversion"? How can I mute the relative warning?

Tags: java, warnings

I have the following line of code:

```
this.Delta = new HashSet[20];
```

where `Delta` is of type `Hashset<Couple>[]`.

The presented line of code generates the warning "Description Resource Path Location Type Type safety: The expression of type HashSet[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to HashSet[] Automata.java    /RAEP line 24 Java Problem".

So:

1. What is an unchecked conversion?
2. How can I fix the warning without a @SuppressWarning line? (I don't like warnings...)
3. How many reputation points can I earn when I vote to close a question?

**EDIT:** I need some more examples to understand what is an unchecked conversion and in my opinion, the linked answer isn't a general solution.